# Immediate Access Violation when debugging Windows.Devices.Sensors project in Windows 7

Tags: c++-cli, interop

I have a large solution with 50+ unmanaged projects in it. I have recently added a project with managed code in it to the solution. The managed code accesses Windows.Devices.Sensors in a .NET dll. This dll is eventually wrapped by unmanaged code and called from another unmanaged project.

My problem is that I get the following access violation before main() even executes.

```
Unhandled exception at 0x744b8ea0 in myApplication.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
```

Managed code:

```
#using <Windows.winmd>
using namespace Windows::Devices::Sensors;

#include <math.h>

namespace TabletSensors 
{
     namespace NET
     {
        public ref class DotNetDllClass
        {
        public:
            DotNetDllClass()
            {
                Initialization();
            }

            ~DotNetDllClass()
            {
            }

            float* GetQuaternion()
            {
                OrientationSensorReading^ reading = _orientation->GetCurrentReading();

                if( reading != nullptr )
                {
                    float* quat = new float[4];

                    quat[0] = reading->Quaternion->X;
                    quat[1] = reading->Quaternion->Y;
                    quat[2] = reading->Quaternion->Z;
                    quat[3] = reading->Quaternion->W;

                    return quat;
                }
                else
                {
                    return NULL;
                }
            }
        private:
            void Initialization()
            {
                _orientation = OrientationSensor::GetDefault();

                if( _orientation != nullptr )
                {
                    _orientation->ReportInterval = 16;
                }
                else
                {
                    // not good ... throw exception or something
                }
            }

            OrientationSensor^ _orientation;
        };
    }
}
```

Wrapper header file:

```
namespace TabletSensors
{
    namespace NETWrapper 
    {
        class DLLEXPORT_SENSORS WrapperClass
        {
        public:
            __stdcall WrapperClass();

            __stdcall ~WrapperClass();

            float* __stdcall GetQuaternion();
        };
    }
}
```

Wrapper cpp file:

```
#define MIXSENSORS_BUILD

#include <gcroot.h>

#include "DotNetWrapper.h"
#include "DotNetDll.h"


using namespace TabletSensors::NETWrapper;
using namespace TabletSensors::NET;

static gcroot<TabletSensors::NET::DotNetDllClass^> Sensors = nullptr;
static System::UInt16 refCount = 0;
#pragma managed 

inline TabletSensors::NET::DotNetDllClass^ GetSensors(void)
{
    return (TabletSensors::NET::DotNetDllClass^)Sensors;
}

void Init()
{
    ++refCount;

    if(GetSensors() == nullptr)
    {
        Sensors = gcnew TabletSensors::NET::DotNetDllClass();
    }
}

void CleanUp()
{
    if( refCount > 0 )
    {
        --refCount;
    }
}

float* GetQuaternion_()
{
    return Sensors->GetQuaternion();
}

#pragma unmanaged

TabletSensors::NETWrapper::WrapperClass::WrapperClass()
{
    Init();
}

TabletSensors::NETWrapper::WrapperClass::~WrapperClass()
{
    CleanUp();
}

float* TabletSensors::NETWrapper::WrapperClass::GetQuaternion()
{
    float* x = new float[4];
    return GetQuaternion_();
}

#pragma managed
```

Unmanaged project referencing my wrapper class:

```
#include "DotNetWrapper.h"
     .
     .
     .
void UnmanagedProject::Update()
{
     // if this line is present, I get an access violation without hitting any breakpoints.
     TabletSensors::NETWrapper::WrapperClass _tabletSensors;
     .
     .
     .
}
```

Since the managed code is trying to access Tablet Sensors I understand why it doesn't work on my Windows 7 desktop.  What I don't understand it why it won't even allow me to debug my code at all. No breakpoints are hit before the Access Violation occurs.

What I would really like to figure out is how to use exception handling or #ifdefs to keep this crash from happening.  But I have had very little luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is to Delay Load the managed DLL.  The allows the application to run until that DLL is explicitly called.  Thanks to Ben Voight for his answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28467701/1454861