# Developing C++/CLI project for Windows 8 Tablet on Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, c++-cli, windows-8.1

I have a code base of native C++. Recently I incorporated a Windows 8 tablet into the system that we deploy to.

I have a .NET managed DLL that accesses the Tablet orientation sensor. This managed code is wrapped by an unmanaged class that I can access from the native C++.

The problem is that I cannot run and debug the code on my Windows 7/VS2010 box without getting an Access Violation at the outset. No breakpoints are even hit before the exception.

Is there a way to ignore the managed DLL while debugging on the Windows 7/VS2010 box?

Comment: Seems strange to write a wrapper for managed code that is almost certainly just a wrapper around more native code.

Comment: Native Sensor API documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318953%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I wasn't aware that Windows 8 sensors could be accessed with the same Sensor API. If I understand you correctly, I could access the Surface Pro 3 orientation sensor using native C++?

Comment: Probably, but I'm not 100% sure.  I would definitely think it would be worthwhile running a sensor browser to see what sensors are visible to that API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delay loading is your friend.  Read the MSDN documentation, starting with [Linker Support for Delay-Loaded DLLs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx).

Comment: This fixed it.  Entering the DLL name into the dependent project's `Linker > Input > Delay Loaded Dlls` setting allows it to run until that DLL is called explicitly.  Thanks!